# Tricky LINQ Query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have been working on some LINQ and I can't seem to figure out how to filter this data.  I am still quite new to LINQ and this is the first real stumbling block I have come across.

I have table:

**TaskID | Name | TypeID | ParentTaskID**

Values:

> 1 | TaskName | 1 | NULL
>
> 2 | TaskName| 6 | NULL
>
> 3 | TaskName| 6 | 4
>
> 4 | TaskName| 2 | NULL
>
> 5 | TaskName| 6 | 4
>
> 6 | TaskName| 3 | 4
>
> 7 | TaskName| 6 | 1
>
> 8 | TaskName| 6 | 1
>
> 9 | TaskName| 2 | NULL

**A SubTask is a Task that has a ParentTaskID.**

I need to get all Tasks with this criteria:

- Remove Task if Task has no allocated SubTasks and a TypeID = 6
- Remove Parent and Subtasks if a ParentTask has SubTasks that ALL have a TypeID = 6

Therefore I would expect to get back

> 3 | TaskName| 6 | 4
>
> 4 | TaskName| 2 | NULL
>
> 5 | TaskName| 6 | 4
>
> 6 | TaskName| 3 | 4
>
> 9 | TaskName| 3 | NULL

The results in the above table are as such:

> TaskID 1 removed because TaskID 7 & 8 are SubTasks with a TypeID = 6
>
> TaskID 2 removed because it has no SubTasks and TypeID = 6
>
> TaskID 7 & 8 removed because they are SubTasks with TypeID = 6 for ParentTask 1

Is it even possible to do this in LINQ or will I have to reside on doing this in a foreach loop?

## MY SOLUTION

So I ended up doing this the old fashioned way with Foreach and letting Resharper convert what it could back into LINQ.

```
        var parents = tasks.Where(task => task.SubTasks.Any());
        var tasksWithNoSubs = tasks.Where(task => !task.SubTasks.Any());
        var parentIdsToRemove = new List<int?>();
        var childIdsToRemove = new List<int?>();

        foreach (var parent in parents)
        {
            var children = tasks.Where(task => task.ParentTaskID == parent.Id);
            if (children.All(task => task.StatusId == 6))
            {
                parentIdsToRemove.Add(parent.Id); //mark this parent for removal
                childIdsToRemove.AddRange(Enumerable.Select(children.Select(child => child.Id), dummy => (int?) dummy));
            }
        }

        //get all Tasks that have NO Subtasks and also have a StatusID = 6
        parentIdsToRemove.AddRange(Enumerable.Select((from task in tasksWithNoSubs where task.StatusId == 6 select task.Id), dummy => (int?) dummy));

        //get a list of children with an Id contained in the list parentIdsToRemove
        var tasksToRemove =
            tasks.Where(task => parentIdsToRemove.Contains(task.Id) || childIdsToRemove.Contains(task.Id));

        //remove the tasks from the collection
        tasks = tasks.Where(task => !tasksToRemove.Contains(task));
```

Comment: Shouldn't 2 and 3 have been removed because 2 has a single subtask which has type 6? (as opposed to just 2 being removed because it had no subtasks)? And shouldn't 9 have been removed because it had no subtasks with an id of 6 (and indeed no subtasks at all)? Wait, for that last one should that first criteria be stated as "Remove tasks with TypeID =6 that have no sub tasks"? I read it as the subtasks having the typeid=6...

Comment: For actually solving it I would imagine that some combination of joining followed by grouping by the parent tasks and then a where clause for each of the two criteria that can look at the grouped subtasks. I'm not sure I can write the query myself but hopefully this will give you an idea to start with.

Comment: Hey Chris, its quite possible I have some of the results incorrect so please excuse me there.  
I have updated the OP now to give 3 a Parent of 4, hopefully that looks correct.

Comment: 9 should not be removed because it has no Sub Tasks and does not have a TypeID = 6

Comment: You need to clarify your first bullet in the actual question.  Is it meant to say "Remove Tasks that have a TypeID of 6 and no SubTasks" or "Remove Tasks with no SubTasks of TypeID = 6"..?  (Note, this is why we should abandon natural language and all speak C++.  Err, sorry, C# - forgot where I was!)

Comment: Edited OP again, yeah sorry its quite hard to write this out in a sentence :)

Comment: shouldn't 5 be removed. Since it does not have any subtasks and type id is 6

Comment: @dcp1986: I think that stays in because it is a subtask and not a task. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Chris is correct, it remains because its a SubTask, this is quite the mind f**k, excuse my language :)

Comment: Looking at my heavily downvoted answer and the only other, I've suddenly picked up another possible ambiguity in your question.  Do you want to actually remove items from the entity set according to your criteria, or just filter them out while leaving the entity set intact?

Comment: Just need to filter them out.

Comment: I'm pretty close to swearing, a lot, right now...  Still, third time lucky.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the solution in the original post (also posted here).

```
    var parents = tasks.Where(task => task.SubTasks.Any());
    var tasksWithNoSubs = tasks.Where(task => !task.SubTasks.Any());
    var parentIdsToRemove = new List<int?>();
    var childIdsToRemove = new List<int?>();

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        var children = tasks.Where(task => task.ParentTaskID == parent.Id);
        if (children.All(task => task.StatusId == 6))
        {
            parentIdsToRemove.Add(parent.Id); //mark this parent for removal
            childIdsToRemove.AddRange(Enumerable.Select(children.Select(child => child.Id), dummy => (int?) dummy));
        }
    }

    //get all Tasks that have NO Subtasks and also have a StatusID = 6
    parentIdsToRemove.AddRange(Enumerable.Select((from task in tasksWithNoSubs where task.StatusId == 6 select task.Id), dummy => (int?) dummy));

    //get a list of children with an Id contained in the list parentIdsToRemove
    var tasksToRemove =
        tasks.Where(task => parentIdsToRemove.Contains(task.Id) || childIdsToRemove.Contains(task.Id));

    //remove the tasks from the collection
    tasks = tasks.Where(task => !tasksToRemove.Contains(task));
```

Thanks for everyone's contribution, def learnt alot more about LINQ.

Answer (score -1):

You should have properties directly on your task object (generated by entity Framework, that includes references to the parent / children, i assumed the parent one is named ParentTask and the children is named Tasks in my sample, rename accordingly. You don't want to use IDs this is very un EF ish, the whole point of EF & linq is to let it handle all the DB denormalisation nonsense & work with object graphs.

```
YourContext.Tasks
    // Only keep those where it isn't true that it contains no tasks while being type 6
    .Where(t=>!((!t.Tasks.Any()) && t.TypeId == 6))
    // Remove all parents that contains subtasks and only have subtasks with type 6
    .Where(t=>!(t.Tasks.Any() && t.Tasks.All(sub=>sub.TypeId == 6)))
    // Same process on the children, if it has a parent and that parent matches the previous filter
    .Where(t=>!(t.ParentTask != null &&(t.ParentTask.Tasks.Any() && t.ParentTask.Tasks.All(sub=>sub.TypeId == 6))))
```

Note this is completely untested, if it doesn't work please provide a link to your compiled model DLL

Comment: My entity is called Task and in it is an Id, TypeId and a ParentTaskId property (as well as numerous others)

Answer (score -3):

**Second Very hefty edit**

Right!  So, third time lucky after a long time and some misunderstandings - here it is in one statement:

```
entities.

// discard tasks of type 6 and with no subtasks
Where(x => !(x.TypeId == 6 && x.ParentTaskId == null && 
      !entities.Any(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId))).

// discard tasks with subtasks where all those subtasks are of type 6
Where(x => !(entities.Any(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId) &&
             entities.Count(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId) ==
             entities.Count(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId && y.TypeId == 6))).

// discard subtasks that have parents that are not to be found in the list of 
// tasks that were not discarded for having subtasks that were all of type 6.
Where(z => z.ParentTaskId == null || 
             entities.Where(x => !(entities.Any(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId) &&
                                   entities.Count(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId) ==
                                   entities.Count(y => y.ParentTaskId == x.TaskId && y.TypeId == 6))).
                                            Any(y => y.TaskId == z.ParentTaskId));
```

Comment: This isn't doing *anything* in EF.  None of this is done on the DB end, which it should be.

Comment: I am getting slightly closer to the solution, will post up when I have it done.

Comment: @nz_dev give that a whirl, I'm gonna lie down.

Comment: @user1158692 I tried this however there was an issue with the data being returned and had to revert to another solution which I have posted up in my original post.